# How can I retrieve an older image for Docker instead of latest?

Tags: docker, downgrade

What command(s) do I have to run to retrieve an older image of a software offered in Docker?

I have problems with the latest image of [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) so I though I could try older versions to see what happens. However, I saw a comment in an issue mentioning editing the YAML file this way:

```
image: localstack/localstack:0.9
```

but no other info... (it was not the point of the issue, so it's understandable).

I've been looking around and saw many posts about getting the latest image (i.e. `docker update ...`), but nothing that would allow me to go back in time except for images that I would happen to already have.

Just the change above had absolutely no effect. I'm wondering how can I get Docker to download an older image so I can run that older one instead of the latest? I'm also wondering about how to find a list of available tags for a given docker to make sure I use a version that actually exists.

Comment: http://www.googlinux.com/list-all-tags-of-docker-image/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for existing tags at desired repo's hub.

If you are using docker-compose the correct way to do it is:

```
image: <image>:<tag>
```

If no tag was found then it is not available or does not exist.

Here are tags available at [localstack hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/localstack/localstack/tags)

Comment: Ah! That command `docker run localstack/localstack:0.10.2` actually worked. I'm not too sure what my other command has which prevented it to work as expected. Oh well... I'll have the image.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, you just did not provide it with a valid tag